# Como ver se uma string possui números inteiros

Tags: c++, string

Nesse programa ele apenas analisa se a string possui dígitos, porém queria que ele analisasse se possui números inteiros positivos. Por exemplo:

entrada:

a 1 b 12 c 3.14 -20

saída:

a +1 b +12 c 3.14 -20

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


bool isdigit(char c)
{
    if(c>='0' && c<='9')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }



int main ()
{
   string str;
   getline(cin, str);

    for (int i=0; i < str.length(); ++i) {

         if (isdigit(str[i])==true){
                cout << " +" << str[i];
         }
         if (isdigit(str[i])==false)
            cout << str[i];
    }

return 0;
}
```

Nesse caso se eu entro com o número 12, ele retorna +1 +2. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Já ouviu falar de máquina de estados?

Comment: não..... o que é?

Comment: Pelo seu exemplo o programa também deve tratar números reais e inteiros negativos. Foi apenas um exemplo ruim ou a definição não está correta?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta

Comment: Se fosse apenas para tratar "números inteiros e positivos" o resultado deveria ser: `a  +1 b  +12 c  +3. +14 - +20` e não`a +1 b +12 c 3.14 -20`. Se deseja fazer um reconhecedor de números (inteiros ou reais) pesquise por máquina de estados finitos ou expressões regulares.

Comment: Você não mencionou "espaço" em sua pergunta, eles são importantes? Você quer analisar a sequência de caracteres entre espaços (exceto o primeiro e o último)?

Comment: não, deixei os espaços só pra conseguir visualizar melhor

Answer (score 0):

Para ter uma solução super robusta vai precisar de lógica complexa, mas para resolver os casos que indica na pergunta não precisa de muito.

Com mais 2 variáveis e alterando apenas no `main` dá para fazer:

```
int main () {
    string str, num = "";
    getline(cin, str);
    char ultima_letra = 0; //para saber se o numero tem um - ou . antes 

    for (size_t i=0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (isdigit(str[i])) {
            num += str[i]; //junta os dígitos para o número
        } else {
            if (num.length() > 0 && str[i] != '.' && ultima_letra != '.' && ultima_letra !='-'){
                cout << "+";
            }
            ultima_letra = str[i];
            cout << num << str[i];
            num = ""; //escreveu o numero por isso tem de limpar
        }
    }
    if (num.length() > 0 && ultima_letra != '.' && ultima_letra !='-'){
        cout << "+";
    }
    cout << num << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[O exemplo que mencionou a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/t02wLq)

A lógica é ir guardando o numero inteiro que vai apanhando numa string, concatenando digito a digito, depois quando apanha uma letra verifica se é um número inteiro positivo consultando a letra anterior e posterior ao número.
Se for um `.` antes ou depois, e se for um `-` antes descarta como numero. Em todos os outros casos considera como número e escreve o `+` antes de escrever o número.

Comment: Aaah muito obrigada! Entendi!!!

Answer (score 0):

Já existe uma função isdigit na biblioteca ctype, não precisa implementar uma.

Adiciona um while pra imprimir todos os dígitos consecutivos:

```
for (int i=0; i < str.length(); ++i)
     if (isdigit(str[i])==true){
            cout << " +";
            while(i < str.length() && isdigit(str[i])) 
               cout << str[i++];
     }
     else
        cout << str[i];
```